# PHP - most lightweight psr-0 compliant autoloader

Tags: php, autoload, psr-0

I have a tiny application that i need an autoloader for.  I could easily use the symfony2 class loader but it seems like overkill.

Is there a stable extremely lightweight psr-0 autloader out there?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You ask extremely lightweight, let's do so ;)

Timothy Boronczyk wrote a nice minimal SPL autoloader : http://zaemis.blogspot.fr/2012/05/writing-minimal-psr-0-autoloader.html

I condensed the code like this:

```
function autoload1( $class ) {
    preg_match('/^(.+)?([^\\\\]+)$/U', ltrim( $class, '\\' ), $match ) );
    require str_replace( '\\', '/', $match[ 1 ] )
        . str_replace( [ '\\', '_' ], '/', $match[ 2 ] )
        . '.php';
}
```

Then compare (minified versions of) this [autoload3] with [short @Alix Axel code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416954/1154106) [autoload4] :

```
function autoload3($c){preg_match('/^(.+)?([^\\\\]+)$/U',ltrim($c,'\\'),$m);require str_replace('\\','/',$m[1]).str_replace(['\\','_'],'/',$m[2]).'.php';}
function autoload4($c){require (($n=strrpos($c=ltrim($c,'\\'),'\\'))!==false?str_replace('\\','/',substr($c,0,++$n)):null).str_replace('_','/',substr($c,$n)).'.php';}
```

autoload3 is the shortest !

Let's use stable & extremely lightweight (175b !) autoloader file :

```
<?php spl_autoload_register(function ($c){preg_match('/^(.+)?([^\\\\]+)$/U',ltrim($c,'\\'),$m);require str_replace('\\','/',$m[1]).str_replace(['\\','_'],'/',$m[2]).'.php';});
```

Maybe i'm crazy but you Asked for extreme, no?

**EDIT:** Thanks to Alix Axel, i've shorten the code (only 100b !) and used include instead of require in case you have various autoloading strategy for old libs (and then various autoloader in spl autoload stack...).

```
<?php spl_autoload_register(function($c){@include preg_replace('#\\\|_(?!.+\\\)#','/',$c).'.php';});
```

If you want to make it shorter / better, please use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/adriengibrat/4761717).

Comment: +1, I haven't tried but I think your version could be even shorter if you use `preg_replace()` instead of `preg_match()` + `str_replace()`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that `preg_match()` is faster than other equivalent PHP options.

Answer (score 15):

The [PSR-0 specification document](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md#splclassloader-implementation) has an examplary compatible autoloader function that is already pretty short:

```
function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}
```

It's usage is pretty straight forward:

```
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

The shortcoming with it is, that you need to configure base-directories it works on with the `include_path` directive. To support a hybrid PSR-0 autoloaders leaned onto SPL semantics, the following one supportss include path and spl autoload extensions:

```
$spl_autoload_register_psr0 = function ($extensions = null) 
{
    $callback = function ($className, $extensions = null) 
    {
        if (!preg_match('~^[a-z0-9\\_]{2,}$~i', $className)) {
            return;
        }
        null !== $extensions || $extensions = spl_autoload_extensions();
        $extensions = array_map('trim', explode(',', $extensions));
        $dirs = array_map('realpath', explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path()));

        $classStub = strtr($className, array('_' => '/', '\\' => '/'));

        foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
            foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
                $file = sprintf('%s/%s%s', $dir, $classStub, $extension);
                if (!is_readable($file)) {
                    continue;
                }
                include $file;
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    return spl_autoload_register($callback);
};
```

The [The Symfony2 ClassLoader Component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html) has the benefit to allow more configuration here. You can install it easily via Pear or Composer ([symfony/class-loader on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/class-loader)). It is a component on it's own that is used by many and fairly well tested and supported.

Comment: Example for PSR-0 autoloader accepting extensions and working on the standard PHP include path: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9066049#9066049

Answer (score 10):

[SplClassLoader](https://gist.github.com/221634) seems like a right choice. It's an implementation [proposed by PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md#splclassloader-implementation) itself.

Comment: It's not exactly what I'd entitle "light weight".

Answer (score 4):

An exact equivalent of [the answer @hakre provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836587/89771), just shorter:

```
function autoload($class) {
  $path = null;

  if (($namespace = strrpos($class = ltrim($class, '\\'), '\\')) !== false) {
    $path .= strtr(substr($class, 0, ++$namespace), '\\', '/');
  }

  require($path . strtr(substr($class, $namespace), '_', '/') . '.php');
}
```

You can also set the base directory by changing `$path = null;` to another value, or just do like this:

```
$paths = array
(
    __DIR__ . '/vendor/',
    __DIR__ . '/vendor/phunction/phunction.php',
);

foreach ($paths as $path)
{
    if (is_dir($path) === true)
    {
        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) use ($path)
        {
            if (($namespace = strrpos($class = ltrim($class, '\\'), '\\')) !== false)
            {
                $path .= strtr(substr($class, 0, ++$namespace), '\\', '/');
            }

            require($path . strtr(substr($class, $namespace), '_', '/') . '.php');
        });
    }

    else if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        require($path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [doctrine classloader](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/class-loading.html) is another good choice. You can easily install it with [composer](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/common)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but I found that the above answers worked great on standalone PHP scripts, but were causing issues when used in certain frameworks, such as Joomla.

For anyone using Joomla, it turns out that there is a compatible autoloader already built into the framework, therefore you won't need to use the above functions.  In that instance, just call JLoader::registerNamespace().... for example:

```
JLoader::registerNamespace('Solarium', JPATH_LIBRARIES . DS . 'solarium-3.2.0' . DS . 'library');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function autoload($fullClassName) {
    $name_elems = explode('\\', $fullClassName);
    require __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $name_elems).'.php';
}
```

This even supports things like:
$transformerContstraint = new \Recurr\Transformer\Constraint\AfterConstraint(new DateTime());

Just put it in /vendor/Recurr/Transformer/Constraint/AfterConstraint.php