# inheritance and external files. How do I go about it?

Tags: php, oop

I have 3 files.

- vehicleClass.php
- motorbikeClass.php (extends vehicleClass)
- index.php

My question is... How do I connect all 3. On my index page, do I have to have

```
include 'classes/vehicleClass.php';
```

Do I need to have an include for the motorbike class or will the extend (inheritence) cover this?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? If you manually want to include all necessary files, I'd recommend `require_once` so you don't get a conflict when including the same class twice - even better: use autoloading!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: a class that is extending (or otherwise using) another class must already have defined the parent class before the definition of the child class.  Your assumption is correct, your `VehicleClass` must be included (or better, `require`'d) prior to your definition of `MotorBike` class.

However, most frameworks don't go about and include *every* depedency before all class definitions.  This would become unwieldy on any system that has any amount of complexity to it.  Instead, the developers of PHP have provided methods for [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) classes.  Using `spl_autoload_register` will allow you to write a function that will attempt to load in the source file for a given class whenever it is referenced but a definition for it has not yet been found.

Furthermore, once you get a system together that becomes complex, you don't want to store all of your files in a single place.  Most frameworks leverage the filesystem and [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) to help better organize all of their classes.  Because of this, the [PSR-0](http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/) standard was developed in order to help facilitate autoloading between frameworks.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082507/php-most-lightweight-psr-0-compliant-autoloader) for examples of PSR-0 compliant autoloaders.

Example of PSR-0 compliant class:

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Package;

class ClassName { }
```

This file would live in the filesystem at `/Vendor/Package/ClassName.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can let php autoload your files, by registering your own autoload function. If you have, in example, all your class files in the directory `DOCROOT . 'classes'` (DOCROOT being your document root), you can use a function like this (example):

```
function class_loader($class) {
    include DOCROOT . 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('class_loader');
```

Now if you try to create an object of class 'foo', it will try to include the file `DOCROOT . '/classes/foo.class.php'` before creating the object. You might want to extend the function a bit, eg. to lowercase file names (`include DOCROOT . 'classes/'. strtolower($class) .'.class.php';`). This way you can place class Foo in foo.class.php.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is include 2 files in the index.php.

For example, your index.php page could be something like this.

```
<?php
require 'classes/vehicleClass.php'; 
require 'classes/motorbikeClass.php';

// Assuming your class name is MotorBike 
$motorBike = new MotorBike();


// And just call the method you want, for example If you have a method called bikeName
echo $motorBike->bikeName();

?>
```

I hope you get an idea now.

P/S: I prefer require over include. :) Include() should work fine too.